# I cant change the logo of transactional emails

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail

I cant change the logo of transactional emails for some reason when I upload ans press SAVE & CONTINUE the picture its showing me like this

```
http://prntscr.com/jiabim
```

Does anyone has found this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: please check the permission of media folder and files

Comment: @PrasantaHatui Can you tell me which permissions do I need to have in order to work?

Comment: Please give 777 for pub/media/ folder and images in order to work.

Comment: @PrasantaHatui I gave 777 for pub/media folder do I need to do anything else to work?

Comment: if till not worked. take the image link by inspecting the browser and enter in browser if image is loading or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Transnational emails logo using backend

Go to

> Admin => Content => Configuration => Edit your theme => Transactional Emails => Logo Image Upload your logo here

Review attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do

Comment: Sorry not getting you. Could you please more explain